# How to cancel tedious Excel charting operation without crash

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze, charts

I'm charting about 17,000 data points in Excel. Needless to say charting is *slowwww*.

I accidentally selected the wrong chart type (Bubble thing?) and it is loading forever. I did not save my last changes.

Is there any way to cancel the operation without crashing Excel and losing my work?

---

It's been 6 minutes and Excel is still loading.

**UPDATE:** After 10 minutes the chart appeared and I was able to change the type, but I would still like an answer for future references, if possible.

Comment: Currently having the same problem. 220 000 data points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there are no way.There are no cancel button or something.Probably you could write some macro for graphs you could include a cancel button there probably.

Comment: Next time I'm waiting for my chart to load, I'll write a macro :)